# Use a yocto layer's recipe or class without inheriting all bbappends

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I want to use a specific class of a given layer or maybe just a given recipe. But I don't want to use anything more, nor that my build gets affected by other bbappend's present in that layer.

What is the way to proceed?

**My specific use case:**

I am writting a recipe which is using qmake5 to build. Therefore I am interested in [qmake5.bbclass](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/blob/master/classes/qmake5.bbclass). The software built in fact has no QT content, but just uses qmake. Therefore I am not interested in the rest of the [meta-qt5 layer](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5)

Comment: You can copy the bbclass into your personnal layer includind its dependencies. You'll have to backport fixes from upstream from time to time then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mask all directories from meta-qt5 later except the classes dir. Add to you local.conf:

BBMASK += "meta-qt5/recipes-*/"

More on BBMASK here:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html